# How to save the image in my project folder using servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="FileUploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
        <input type="file"  name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my index.jsp,when i submit it goes to FileUploadServlet.i.e.,

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (isMultiPart) {
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        try {
            FileItemIterator itr = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = itr.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    InputStream is = item.openStream();
                    byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
                    is.read(b);
                    String value = new String(b);
                    response.getWriter().println(fieldname + ":" + value + "</br>");
                } else {
                    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    if (FileUpload.processFile(path, item)) {
                        response.getWriter().println("Upload Success");
                    } else {
                        response.getWriter().println("Upload Failed");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException fue) {
            fue.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Servlet and  the following code is FileUpload java class

```
public class FileUpload {

public static boolean processFile(String path, FileItemStream item) {
    try {
        File f = new File(path + File.separator + "images");
        if(!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdir();
        }
        File savedFile=new File(f.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+item.getName());
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(savedFile);
        InputStream is=item.openStream();
        int x=0;
        byte[]b=new byte[1024];
        while((x=is.read(b))!=-1){
            fos.write(b,0,x);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

This is working fine but the problem is when image file is uploaded that are saving in `C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageUpload\build\web\images) but my requirement is image has to store inside project folder called images i.e.,(C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageUpload\web\images),can you guide me where to change the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it and tell me how it went

Answer (score 1):

Okay i will give you the shoretest and easiest solution

- First create the servlet and add following lines to at top servlet clas
- @WebServlet(name = "FileUploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
- @MultipartConfig
- Then inside post method copy and paste the content inside post method that i have posted below then
- Then Copy the funciton getFileName and paste it below doPost() method

### The HTML form in tut-install/examples/web/fileupload/web/index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            File:
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
            Destination:
            <input type="text" value="/tmp" name="destination"/>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


A POST request method is used when the client needs to send data to the server as part of the request, such as when uploading a file or submitting a completed form. In contrast, a GET request method sends a URL and headers only to the server, whereas POST requests also include a message body. This allows arbitrary-length data of any type to be sent to the server. A header field in the POST request usually indicates the message body’s Internet media type.

When submitting a form, the browser streams the content in, combining all parts, with each part representing a field of a form. Parts are named after the input elements and are separated from each other with string delimiters named boundary.

This is what submitted data from the fileupload form looks like, after selecting sample.txt as the file that will be uploaded to the tmp directory on the local file system:

POST /fileupload/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
boundary=---------------------------263081694432439
Content-Length: 441
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Data from sample file
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="destination"

/tmp
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"

Upload
-----------------------------263081694432439--
The servlet FileUploadServlet.java can be found in the tut-install/examples/web/fileupload/src/java/fileupload/ directory. The servlet begins as follows:

@WebServlet(name = "FileUploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(FileUploadServlet.class.getCanonicalName());
```

The @WebServlet annotation uses the urlPatterns property to define servlet mappings.

The @MultipartConfig annotation indicates that the servlet expects requests to made using the multipart/form-data MIME type.

The processRequest method retrieves the destination and file part from the request, then calls the getFileName method to retrieve the file name from the file part. The method then creates a FileOutputStream and copies the file to the specified destination. The error-handling section of the method catches and handles some of the most common reasons why a file would not be found. The processRequest and getFileName methods look like this:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // Create path components to save the file
    final String path = request.getParameter("destination");
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                + fileName));
        filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File{0}being uploaded to {1}", 
                new Object[]{fileName, path});
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
        writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                + "location.");
        writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}", 
                new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (filecontent != null) {
            filecontent.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

private String getFileName(final Part part) {
    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

## Code to Add File to a folder Dynamically ##

```
 String filePath = "D:\\folder1Name\\folder2Name\\";




if (request.getPart("file") != null) {
            if (request.getPart("file").getSize() != 0) {
                System.out.println(UName + "UName" + "LoopilKeri");
                final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
                String folderName = filePath + UName + "//file";//path;
                final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);
                //
                 File file = new File(folderName);
                  if (!file.exists()) {
                 file.mkdirs();
                 }

                OutputStream out = null;
                InputStream filecontent = null;
                final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(folderName + File.separator
                            + fileName));
                    filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    int read = 0;
                    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                // byte[] byte1 = new byte[1024];
                    //   byte1=IOUtils.toByteArray(filecontent);
                    //  System.out.println(byte1.toString()); 
                    while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        sb.append(bytes);
                        System.out.println(bytes);
                        System.out.println(bytes + "0here" + read);

                        out.write(bytes, 0, read);

                    }
                    // writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + folderName);
                    System.out.println("###########################################################################");
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    request.setAttribute("f1", folderName);
                    request.setAttribute("f2", fileName);
                    //   request.setAttribute("f", byte1);
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    System.out.println("###########################################################################");
                    ServletContext se = this.getServletContext();
                // RequestDispatcher rd =se.getRequestDispatcher("/NewServlet");
                    // rd.forward(request, response);
                    //      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File{0}being uploaded to {1}", 
                    //              new Object[]{fileName, folderName});
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
//                writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
//                        + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
//                        + "location.");
//                writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

                    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}",
                            new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
                } finally {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (filecontent != null) {
                        filecontent.close();
                    }
                    if (writer != null) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: whether it will store image inside project folder?

Comment: This actually show how to upload file i will give you the customised code

Comment: Now it will upload anything

Comment: path should not be hard coded like String filePath = "D:\\folder1Name\\folder2Name\\"; this,see the code attached in my question and if possible tell me where to change it

Comment: for my code also upload image is working fine but what the problem is image is saving in projectname\build\web\images but image should save in projectname\web\images.

Comment: Are you trying to create path or folder dynamically

Comment: yes ofcourse,please check my code ,File f = new File(path + File.separator + "images");this i have written

Comment: Can You please give SysO of  String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

Comment: String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); i already added in my code

Comment: No no i wanted to know the value of path variable

Comment: i'm getting the path as:C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageUpload\build\web\images but i need the path is C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageUpload\web\images

Comment: Is imageupload yourproject name if yes where is your servlet located i mean in which folder In my Pc getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); returns my project folder

Comment: I think the array shouldn't be hardcoded to 1024? What if I had a file larger than that? I think it should read from the header for the file size.

Comment: @CyberMew  Yea sure its a better way

Comment: very well explained, your answer is the solution for me after wasting 5 hours for uploading file using servlet, thanks a lot sir +1

Comment: Thanks this is the easiest way to do it I hope this question got more attention and votes

Answer (score 1):

first in servlet you need to mention

```
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, 
maxFileSize=1024*1024*10, 
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)
```

Setting the file size and then you should mention the path and try to save in database.

you can see the complete code [HERE](http://javainfinite.com/jsp-and-servlet/saving-image-in-folder-and-path-in-database-using-java/)